# Magento 2.0 Adding a custom page

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento.Most of the learning stuff in the web deals with the older versions.What I am trying to do is to add  custom web pages with the navigation buttons in the main menu via cms.
I am doing this:

1. Go to Content - > Pages -> Add New Page.Under the "Page information" tab I set  a name for "Url key".Let's call it "aboutus" (for about us page)
2. Go to Products -> Categories. Click "Add subcategory" an under "General Information" I write "aboutus" in the "Url key" field.

The button appears in the navigation panel,but when I press it, it doesn't take me to the page I created.At least that's how it looks like, because I don't see the content I wrote but just this text:

> Compare Products
>
> You have no items to compare.
>
> My Wish List
>
> You have no items in your wish list.

So my question is what I do wrong and is it even possible to create completely custom pages via the admin system.

Using Magento 2.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Here the routing system is different, when you click on Navigation `aboutus` . the request is from Catalog-> Category so it looks for categories.

Two : This is from CMS page routing ( Content - > Pages ), if you want to see the page you added go `http://mydomain/aboutus` and you can get the exact page.

If you try to duplicate the Url Key values ( again add new page with same url  key in CMS )it throws `URL key for specified store already exists.`

**Add or redirect category link  to content block.**

1. Create new block Content > Blocks > Add New Block.
2. Go to category 
   Display Settings > Display Mode ( Select Static block only ) > CMS Block ( select your block name )  and save

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem.But you don't provide the answer to my question.

Comment: I need to have that link on the main menu  category button.Not on some custom link text or html element.I set main navigation bar with categories like "Contacts" ,About Us" etc.And I need to link to those categories my custom pages.